# Cannot use apt/curl/wget/git but can Ping

Tags: networking, 20.04, iptables, firewall, netplan

I have a raspberry pi running ubuntu server 20 and cannot connect to the internet, but can use ping.  This question has been asked by many before, however the solutions provided in those questions do not solve my issue.

I can ping www.ubuntu.com

```
64 bytes from cactuar.canonical.com (91.189.88.180): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=118 ms
```

but I cannot use sudo apt update

```
Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.150), connection timed out
```

I get similar errors when using curl.  I have checked my iptables and i dont see anything

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 113 packets, 8043 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 71 packets, 7411 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I have UFW disabled (ufw status):

```
Status: inactive
```

I set a static IP via netplan and the file is below (cat /etc/netplan/netconf.yaml) and created the /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [100.65.225.70/24]
      gateway4: 100.65.225.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

The ouput of ip addr show is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:01:4f:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.65.225.70/24 brd 100.65.225.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:54:1a:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have read that something could be blocking port 80, but I am not seeing anything doing so.  Can someone please let me know what else could cause this issue?

Comment: The indentation appears to be very wrong in the netplan file. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ip addr show` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 updated with ip addr show output.  The netscan indentation should be ok.  If it wasnt I think it would complain when i apply the changes.

Comment: @chili555 also updated the netplan file on the machine and the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to download

```
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SY/SYP/Net-Curl-0.44.tar.gz
```

Does this download?

Are there any rules in iptables?

```
ip6tables -nxvL
iptables -nxvL
```

Are you behind any other external firewall?

Comment: I cannot download via wget.  There were no iptables set by me.  When I used dynamic IP I was able to download things but when I went to Static it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove all files in /etc/netplan and set a file 00-installer-config.yaml in place.

```
# network config
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

This will enable dhcp and see if wget download is working now.
Also would be interesting to see output of

```
ip addr
```

Comment: WHen i reverted back to enable dhcp4 for a dynamic IP I was able to download.

Comment: Then it sounds like your router doesn't like letting your traffic through when using an IP not assigned by the dhcp server.

Comment: I think there is a firewall on any other server that is responsible for this 'feature'.